WFE is not working and showing error 500
i have 2 WFE in sharepoint 2019 farm one of them is working fine second one is not loading main site port 80 and showing error :
WFE02 is curranty unable to handle the request error 500
but if i try to open another site collection with different port number it is opening
what can be reason and how to solve this issue
